# Free Your Positive/Negative Energy - Which one means what?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

How the sentence means when I interchange the words?

"Free your positive energy".

Does it mean "now let your positive energy play a positive role to your life"?

While using the "negative" word, does it means "now let the negativity go from your life"?

Let me know what I'm thinking if it's right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The verb 'Free' in this context means remove/release/give freedom.

> Free your positive energy.

This means release (in happiness) the positive energy in you. As this would lead to good life of yours.

On the other hand, if you want the negative energy to go away from your life, you'd probably say...

> **Free your life (or yourself) from** the negative energy. Or else, it'll harm you.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for clean explanation. I got it.